# Median Absolute Deviation: setting constant factor to 1 in stat_summary (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, median, summary

When calculating the median absolute deviation (MAD) via `fun.data = median_mad` using the function `stat_summary` in `ggplot2`, the constant factor is set to 1.4826 by default. However, I want to s**et the constant factor to 1 in the `stat_summary` function**.

When calculating the MAD individually using the `mad` function, it can be adjusted easily by changing
`mad(x, center = median(x), constant = 1.4826)` to `mad(x, center = median(x), constant = 1)`
But how can this be done in summary statistics for a dataframe with 6 factor levels?

The command I use for plotting this is:

```
graph+
stat_summary(fun.data = median_mad, geom = "linerange")
```

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `fun.args` argument of `stat_summary`?

Comment: Thank you @yarnabrina but when adding
`stat_summary(fun.data = median_mad, geom = "linerange", fun.args = list(constant = 1))`

or

`stat_summary(fun.data = median_mad, geom = "linerange", fun.args = list(mult = 1))`

it only returns 
`1: Computation failed in `stat_summary()`:
unused argument (constant = 1) `

Comment: can you please share the `median_mad` function you are using? I'll give it a try on my system.

Comment: @yarnabrina thank you for the offer! In the meantime, I managed to bypass the issue via defining a new function (see below). This worked well. Thank you anyway for your support!

Answer (score 0):

This workaround may do the trick: defining a new function as follows

```
data_summary <- function(x) {
  median <- median(x)
  sigma1 <- median-0.6745*mad(x)
  sigma2 <- median+0.6745*mad(x)
  return(c(y=median,ymin=sigma1,ymax=sigma2))
}
```

The scaling factor 0.6745 adjusts the MAD to constant = 1 (1 / 1.4826 = 0.6745).

Then using

```
geom_line(stat="summary", fun.y=data_summary, fun.ymax=max, fun.ymin=min)
```

instead of

```
stat_summary(fun.data = median_mad, geom = "linerange")
```